# ¿Cómo debo Instalar el controlador MongoDB en PHP?

Tags: php, mongodb

Tengo Laragon con PHP 7.2.11 en un Windows 8. 
¿Como debo instalar el controlador de MongoDB? En `php.ini` he puesto `extension=php_mongo_db.dll`, pero no tengo el archivo DLL correspondiente, y `phpinfo()` no menciona mongo DB por ninguna parte.

Comment: Echale un ojo a la documentación oficial de Laragon, de como puedes instalar MongoDB: https://forum.laragon.org/topic/172/tutorial-how-to-install-mongodb-extension/2

Comment: la dll se encuentra en tu carpeta de instalacion de mongoDB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tengo la misma configuración y plataforma que tu. Lo primero lanzar un `phpinfo()` y buscar la clave `Thread Safe`. Si te pone enabled, busca en https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb/1.6.1/windows los paquetes **7.2 Thread Safe (TS) x64** o **7.2 Thread Safe (TS) x86** (depende de si tu procesador es de 64 o de 32 bits; si tienes Windows 8, muy probablemente es de 64).

Si `Thread Safe` no aparece enabled en `phpinfo()` busca, en la misma URL los paquetes **7.2 Non Thread Safe (NTS) x64** o **7.2 Non Thread Safe (NTS) x86**.

En mi caso, el paquete correcto era **7.2 Thread Safe (TS) x64**. Descárgalo, y ábrelo con 7zip, o alguna otra herramienta similar. Copia el archivo **php_mongodb.dll** en el directorio **ext** de PHP. Como comentas que ya tienes la extensión activada en **php.ini**, solo reinicia Apache. En `phpinfo()` verás ahora toda la información del controlador MongoDB.

Comment: Funcionó. Gracias a los dos.

Comment: Una pregunta: como trabaja MongoDB en un servidor? No de manera local, gracias!